# updating blackberry playbook app on store

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

We have our "Hello-Hello Spanish" application ready for sale on blackberry  app world. Earlier, We have created this application by using  flex builder. Since now playbook OS 2.0 comes out, we are planning to convert our existing  android application :- "Hello-Hello Spanish"  to blackberry playbook app using app player.

We have already repackage the application from android to blackberry and want to send as a update for our existing  app on app world.But we are getting the following error while uploading:-"File bundle (Hello_Hello_Spain.bar) has been rejected. Package ID is required for all .bar file. If this is an upgrade, Package ID must match Package ID in original file bundle."

This error clearly show that our new app product ID does not match with the existing app product ID on app world. but we can not put the same product ID as we have in our existing app. because in our earlier app we have the product ID:- "HHSpanish" but in  our latest version app product ID name is:- "com.hello-hello.HHSpanish". We can not change this android app Product ID as android  project need  product ID at least in 2 segment( for example:- com. abcd).So we are not able to put the same Product ID as we have before.

How can we solve this problem and can send our application as an updated to our existing app?

Another question is:- Does blackberry  playbook have any kind of promo code of app or any gift mechanism  that we can give it to our users so that they can download  our  paid app for free from app world? if not,  please tell us  how can i gift my app to user for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no way to gift your app to customers through AppWorld, BTW, it would have been preferable to post each question in a separate thread.